# How to move to a specific coordinate and click using JXBrowser?

Tags: jxbrowser

JXBrowser supports clicking on some elements on the webpage but our project's requirements need the ability to move a specific coordinate and click on that location. How can this be achieved using JXBrowser?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that using JxBrowser. You can use standard **java.awt.Robot** to move mouse cursor and click on that location.

Comment: @Valdimir .. just trying to get your attention: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800045/jxbrowser-what-is-globalx-globaly-windowx-windowy-in-relation-to-x-y-for-f