# JXBrowser - What is globalX, globalY, windowX, windowY in relation to x, y for forwarding mouse events?

Tags: jxbrowser

I can find no explanation on what these are actually supposed to do.

There are examples on:

https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000102480-forwarding-mouse-events

but 629 and 373 ? I can't figure out what those values are for. I can get the same behaviour with any value for those.

What if you one also sets windowX and windowY ?

What would they do to the result click?

**I am looking to be able to click  and move on a google map. Is that possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **x** and **y** values define the mouse event coordinate inside the browser content area.

The **globalX** and **globalY** values define the screen coordinate of the mouse event.

The **windowX** and **windowY** are deprecated. If you set them, this doesn't affect anything.

For more detailed information about working with Google Maps, please take a look at the [article](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012874-google-maps).

Comment: The globalX and globalY values define the screen coordinate of the mouse event ? What does that mean? I meand when I mouseclick, using the builder, i can set both x,y. Are you saying I can click on x,y but pretend as if it was somplace else? Let me know how these work together. 

Also, the examples  for google map assumes you have access to the google map object. I am crawling a site, and that object is private. I would like to position the map as if I moused myself so I can position it for a screenshot.

Comment: It would be great if one could get access to private members somehow. The chrome inspector seems to be able to get access, at least on breakpoint. I wonder if it is possible to integrate with the inspector. I think Intellij has a debugger plugin that integrates with the inspector, so it's probably possible.

Comment: **What does that mean? I meand when I mouseclick, using the builder, i can set both x,y. Are you saying I can click on x,y but pretend as if it was somplace else? Let me know how these work together.**
You must pass appropriate X and Y coordinate and the screen position coordinate which corresponds to the X,Y. If you don't pass any of these values, this event will be ignored by Chromium engine.

Comment: Nikita, the don't seem to be ignored with the values I tested back then. Could you give me an example? Say Window frame is drawn at {20, 30} and is {400, 600} in size. I need to click on an element which using javascript in the browser itself has determined to be on offset = {430, 200}. That is the element offset relative to the window object ( within the browser ). What would I need to consider here?

Answer (score 0):

Your browserView must be active/focused first!
Then, let's do this way:

```
public static void simulateMouseClickOnElement(Browser browser, BrowserView browserView, DOMElement element){       
        Rectangle rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();                 
        Point ptOnScreen = new Point(rect.x  , rect.y );         
        SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(ptOnScreen, browserView);         
        forwardMouseClickEvent(browser,MouseButtonType.PRIMARY,rect.x,rect.y, ptOnScreen.x, ptOnScreen.y);       
    }
```

JxBrowser is the BEST automation or crawling/hacking tool! Selenium is a best alternative choice due to the TCO.